# Can Flash Builder 4 Premium compile Flex Builder 3 Pro project?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, adobe, flexbuilder, flash-builder

That's about it.  Oh, and I don't want to convert the Flex Builder Project making it incompatible with Flex Builder 3 Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can compile the project with Flash Builder 4. ISTR it either silently updated my project settings or I might have converted the project.

In any case, if you are trying to simultaneously use Flex Builder 3 and Flash Builder 4 you should note that at least one of the internal eclipse & FB project settings files (.actionScriptProperties, .flexProperties & .project) changed format between FB3 and FB4 - I can't remember exactly which ones changed off the top of my head.

This **will** affect your development workflow.

I have previously used Flash Builder 4 on a project whilst the rest of the team was using Flex Builder 3. Whenever they updated their project I had a lot of problems with conflicts in at least one of the above files. Whenever this happened, I just accepted the FB3 versions of the files, and let FB4 internally deal with upgrading the format. If I somehow needed to make changes to those files (such as adding a new class), I'd either get another team member to do it, use FB3 to add the files, or just manually edit the file myself. Irritating, but not the end of the world.

YMMV.

Comment: Thanks!  Don't know what ISTR and YMMV mean, but thanks for sharing your experience.  Exactly what I needed to know to make a decision.

Comment: ISTR - I Seem To Recall & YMMV - Your Mileage May Vary (a generic disclaimer) - I forget that not everyone speaks ye-olde dialects of Internet speak :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  Here is an [article and video](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flexbuilder3_to_flashbuilder4.html) that shows how to use the Flex 3 SDK in Flash Builder 4.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Adobe products are extremely backwards compatible.  However, some Adobe products will by default save your "older" files into the newer format - ie if you saved your FB 3 project with the FB 4 application, you may have to choose "Save As" to force it to save it as version 3 (this is true at least for Flash, not certain if Flex is different in that regard).  This is only relevant if you need to retain the older file format for compatibility with other coworkers who only have an older version of the program.

Comment: That brings up another question just for clarification.  Could one also create a new project that is compatible with Flex Builder 3 using Flash Builder 4?  Are you speculating based on past experience with Adobe projects or do you currently have Flash Builder 4 Premium?